# How to integrate instagram images into a classic asp web site

Tags: instagram

I have a Classic ASP website and I want to display the latest two Instagram Images set up by my client. How do I go about it? I have found an example for PHP but no examples for Classic ASP. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Instagram API for this. You will have to sign up in Instagram and generate the API access token which you'll need to use in the code (below). The user ID will also have to be changed to your user ID (this is a numeric value)

The API will return result as JSON which you'll have to parse using the standard JSON2.asp. You can get it here:
https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp

Here's the code:

```
<!--#include file="JSON2.asp"-->
<%

    Const MaxNum = 2

    Set xmlHTTP = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    xmlHTTP.open "GET", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/<userID>/media/recent/?access_token=<your Instagram access token>", false
    xmlHTTP.send()
    RawFeed = xmlHTTP.ResponseText

    Set RawResults = JSON.parse(join(array(RawFeed)))

    iCt = 0
    For Each Feed In RawResults.Get("data")

     if Feed.Get("type") = "image" then
        iCt = iCt + 1
        sURL = Feed.Get("images").Get("thumbnail").Get("url")       ' Can use "low_resolution" or "standard_resolution" instead of "thumbnail" for images in other resolutions
        sLink = Feed.Get("link")
        response.write "<a href=""" & sLink & """><img src=""" & sURL & """></a>"

        if iCt = MaxNum then exit for
     End If

    Next
%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to do it using Ajax and Jquery in the end but your version should work as well

Comment: That answer worked very well for me but interested to see your JQuery/Ajax solution too.